# сетевое подключение между компьютерами на сокетах в java

Tags: java, сокеты

пишу игру на java,необходимо реализовать в ней так называемый мультиплеер(ограничимся 2-мя игроками), и обязательным условием является написание всего этого на сокетах...в интернете находил информацию и даже примеры кода клиент-сервер,но они эти примеры работали только в рамках одного компьютера,а необходимо подключение игроков друг к другу с разный устройств(в идеале по интернету,т.е. чтобы люди могли буквально из разных точек мира подключиться друг к другу). Может подкинете примеры кода или статей/литературы,где можно их посмотреть? Я в этой теме на данный момент вообще разбираюсь,поэтому если что-то не правильно сформулировал или сказал - сильно не вините.

Answer (score 1):

я изучал сокеты по этому примеру. https://habrahabr.ru/post/69136/
Это частный случай http cервера. Задавай вместо Local host адрес другой машинки и свой порт и будет Вам счастье. Но тут нужно внимательно проследить за фаерволами что бы они не резали этот трафик.

Comment: спасибо,изучу)только вопросик...если я хочу,чтобы один игрок был хостом, а второй подключался,то первый игрок как бы и будет сервером...вопрос:если порт я могу заранее придумать и прописать в игре, то адрес машинки какой надо указывать?

Comment: А вот в вашем вопросе и скрыта суть не зная публичного IP или хоста вы собственно и не знаете куда коннектиться... Затем и используются веб сервера... Участники объявляют свои реквизиты на них... Как вариант клиенты ручками вводят данные необходимые для соединения... Так было

Comment: нужно прописывать адрес машины в интернете, для этого должен быть белый адрес у провайдера и вам нужно пробросить порт наружу. Вообще такое лучше делать через сервер куда подключаются обе машинки. Можно конечно и так но от игрока что на машине сервере будет требоваться умение настраивать роутеры. Что не всегда просто